# SQL Server replacing only abbreviation within a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, replace, data-cleaning

Within SQL Server I am cleaning strings to remove abbreviations within a street name:

```
-- Replace cl, cl., cl , with Close
SELECT @CleanedAddress = REPLACE(@CleanedAddress, 'cl', ' Close')
WHERE  @CleanedAddress LIKE '% cl'

SELECT @CleanedAddress = REPLACE(@CleanedAddress, ' cl.', ' Close')
WHERE  @CleanedAddress LIKE '% cl.'

SELECT @CleanedAddress = REPLACE(@CleanedAddress, ' cl ', ' Close ')
WHERE  @CleanedAddress LIKE '% cl %'

SELECT @CleanedAddress = REPLACE(@CleanedAddress, ' cl. ', ' Close ')
WHERE  @CleanedAddress LIKE '% cl. %'
```

Given an example street name of 12 Closet Close written as `12 Closet Cl` I can successfully match using the following:

```
SELECT @CleanedAddress = REPLACE(@CleanedAddress, 'cl', ' Close')
WHERE  @CleanedAddress LIKE '% cl'
```

However, the replace changes the all occurrences of 'cl' resulting in `12 Closeoset Close`

How can I replace the ending "Cl" with "Close" rather than all occurrences of "CL" and apply this to work with thousands of strings that might end with "CL"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a RIGHT string instead, I've specifically gone for right 3, so that you would look for a space followed by the cl - This prevents it picking up on any road name ending 'cl'.

```
SELECT @CleanedAddress = LEFT(@CleanedAddress, len(@CleanedAddress) -3) + ' Close'
WHERE  Right(@CleanedAddress,3) = ' cl'
```

Your other instances where you were already looking for a '% cl. %' would work as they are, its just that first one which is more likely to provide false matches

Answer (score 0):

You can do something more general as:

```
SELECT @CleanedAddress = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(' ' + @CleanedAddress + ' ', ' cl ', 'Close ') ) )
WHERE  @CleanedAddress LIKE '% cl%'
```